# Express ignoring assets list and including every javascript file

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, gruntjs

I'm having some trouble figuring our why express is attaching every javascript file in my bower modules instead of just the ones I specify in the assets.json file. I get the feeling it's a daft mistake somewhere, I just don't understand where!

My assets file looks like so:

```
{
"css": {
    "public/build/css/dist.min.css": [

        "public/lib/angular-snap/angular-snap.min.css",
        "public/lib/animate.css/animate.min.css",
        "public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "public/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "public/lib/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.css",
        "public/lib/intro.js/minified/introjs.min.css",
        "public/lib/ng-table/ng-table.css",
        "public/lib/leaflet-dist/leaflet.css",
        "public/lib/leaflet.markerclusterer/dist/MarkerCluster.css",
        "public/lib/leaflet.markerclusterer/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css",
        "public/css/common.css"
    ]
},
"js": {
    "public/build/js/dist.min.js": [
        "public/lib/angular/angular.min.js",
        "public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js",
        "public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js",
        "public/lib/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js",
        "public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
        "public/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js",
        "public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
        "public/lib/angular-snap/angular-snap.min.js",
        "public/lib/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.js",
        "public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.min.js",
        "public/lib/d3/d3.min.js",
        "public/lib/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.min.js",
        "public/lib/intro.js/minified/intro.min.js",
        "public/lib/leaflet-dist/leaflet.js",
        "public/lib/leaflet-plugins/layer/tile/Google.js",
        "public/lib/leaflet.markerclusterer/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js",
        "public/lib/modernizr/modernizr.js",
        "public/lib/momentjs/min/moment.min.js",
        "public/lib/ng-table/ng-table.js",
        "public/lib/snapjs/snap.min.js",
        "public/lib/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.min.js",
        "public/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js",
        "public/lib/underscore.string/dist/underscore.string.min.js",
        "public/*/*.js",
        "public/*/*/*.js"
    ]
}
```

}

I create an assets variable in express.js here:

```
// Import your asset file
    var assets = require('./assets.json');
    assetmanager.init({
        js: assets.js,
        css: assets.css,
        debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),
        webroot: 'public'
    });
```

And finally add these to my view using an each loop in my jade template

```
- each file in assets.js
script(type='text/javascript' src=file)
```

What I'm expecting to happen is that all the scripts I've listed in assets.json be added to my template. Instead it seems to include all .js files under public/lib - which as you can imagine causes some unusual results.

A sample of which is here

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/animate.css/Gruntfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/highcharts-ng/Gruntfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/highcharts-ng/karma.conf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/intro.js/intro.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a daft mistake. The last two rules in my assets file included the lib folder because of the asterisks.